# как сделать чтоб шарик упал по физике без отпрыга по центру экрана, Python

Tags: python

```
import pygame as pg
from time import sleep
import sys

pg.init()
win = pg.display.set_mode((1400,600))

myfont = pg.font.SysFont('Arial',32)

x, y = 300,100

F = 10

V0 = 0

a = 0.07



while True:
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
    label = myfont.render(str(V0),1,(0,0,0))
    #if y < 1350:
    y += V0    
    if V0 < F and  y < 1357:
        V0 += a
    else:
        V0 = -V0/3
        y += V0
    sleep(0.0006)  

    win.fill((0,255,0))
    win.blit(label,(0,0))
    pg.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(x,y),25)
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Не знаю о каком отпрыге вы говорите, но упругое тело отпрыгивает от упругих препятствий, с которыми сталкивается (если для этого достаточно сил)

Comment: хорошо, я прошу чтоб люди сделали мне программу в готорой шарик отпрыгивает от нижнего края окна, только. но никак не посередине

Comment: Определите размер экрана. Поставьте условие на границе размера.  У вас даже всё есть в коде. Хотя я не понял прикола, размер окна (x,y) = (1400, 600), а проверка в коде `y < 1357`,  хотя максимум y = 600

Comment: я случайно перепутал максимум х = 600, а у = 1400